# What happens if a person dies while using Helena G. Wells' time machine?

Tags: time-travel, warehouse-13

In the *Warehouse 13* universe, [Helena G.Wells'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helena_G._Wells) "Time Machine" works by creating a [mental link](http://warehouse13.wikia.com/wiki/H.G._Wells%27_Time_Machine) to a person in the past.

[image: picture of person in time machine]

What would happen if the person whose body the user hijacks (for 22 hours and 19 minutes) gets killed while the user's mind is still in the body?

Comment: This sounds nothing like the mechanism in H.G. Wells' book "The Time Machine".

Comment: That's why it's tagged 'warehouse-13'

Comment: @MonseFoster - I've made the question a bit clearer

Comment: Per the Warehouse 13 wiki; "If the time machine is damaged while in use the user(s) consciousnesses will be lost forever as soon as time runs out". This strongly suggests that the overriding consciousness will simply disappear and the original consciousness will re-impose itself if the time traveller dies. The opposite is presumably true, if the host body dies, the user would return to their own time

Comment: @Valorum that excerpt leads me to think that if anything goes wrong then all is lost. OR... that the living body would retain the guest consciousness. that wiki makes it sounds like the mine is sent like a file from a computer. if the "internet connection" goes down then the file can't get back home. the question that remains from there is will the guest mind fizzle when time expires or just stay there (my guess is fizzle, it doesn't belong there)